# How to send messenger to discord when my service have update

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a service, how do I automatically send a message to Discord when my service has an update?
I try to like that

```
import discord
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
from discord.ext import commands

class DiscordBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = "token"
        self.imageFolder = "folder"
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True
        intents.members = True

        self.client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
        self.bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents,description="Một con bot Ree đến từ stock-chat")
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.create_task(self.client.start(self.token))
        # self.thread = Thread(target=self.loop.run_forever)
        # self.thread.start()



    async def sendMessage(self, content_message):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                    if not member.bot:
                        await member.send("Welcome!")

    def runbot(self):
        self.bot.run(self.token,reconnect=True)
        

bot_discord = DiscordBot()
bot_discord.runbot()
bot_discord.sendMessage("Welcome!")
```

But I cant call sendMessage after call runbot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do something after `bot.run()` because it is blocking call.
However you can call `sendMessage()` from [`on_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_ready) event which is async function:

```py
async def on_ready(self) -> None:
    await sendMessage()
```

But here it is worth to mention that `on_ready` may be executed more than one time. To prevent next triggering it is possible to create a flag `was_ready_once`:

```py
class DiscordBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = "token"
        self.imageFolder = "folder"
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True
        intents.members = True

        self.client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
        self.bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, description="Một con bot Ree đến từ stock-chat")
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.create_task(self.client.start(self.token))
        self._was_ready_one = False  # create flag
        self._add_events()  # add event handlers

    async def sendMessage(self, content_message):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                if not member.bot:
                    await member.send("Welcome!")

    def _add_events(self):  # function to add event handler
        @self.bot.event
        async def on_ready():
            if not self._was_ready_once:  # check if bot was ready before
                self._was_ready_once = True
                await self.sendMessage("content")

    def runbot(self):
        self.bot.run(self.token, reconnect=True)


bot_discord = DiscordBot()
bot_discord.runbot()
```

In addition I'd strongly recommend you to learn how to inherit your custom Bot class from `commands.Bot`, like in the [example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v2.3.2/examples/advanced_startup.py).

This will allow you not to use function like `_add_events()` and define event handlers in the class' body.